# JS weeks, hours and days to seconds.. and back again

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to convert a number of weeks, days and hours to seconds and then convert them back again.

When I convert them back, days and hours are not correct:

```
var weeks = 3,
days = 5,
hours = 1;

//convert to seconds
sec_in_w = weeks * 604800,
sec_in_d = days * 86400,
secs_in_h = hours * 3600,
secs = sec_in_w + sec_in_d + secs_in_h;

//convert back to weeks, days, and hours 
new_w = Math.floor(secs / 604800);
secs -= new_w;
new_d = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
secs -= new_d;
new_h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);

console.log('weeks: ' + new_w);
console.log('days: ' + new_d);
console.log('hour: ' + new_h);
```

DEMO:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avZwBp

Comment: It's because of the Math.floor you're using

Comment: @romuleald, sorry but not it's not. Math.floor is fine here. The problem is in the substracting of the number of weeks without converting them back to seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//convert back to weeks, days, and hours     
new_w = Math.floor(secs / 604800);
secs = secs % 604800;
new_d = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
secs = secs % 86400;
new_h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
```

Using Modulus gives the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting the number of weeks and days, not the number of seconds in the weeks or days.

```
secs -= new_w * 604800; 
new_d = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
secs -= new_d * 86400;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to subtract the number of weeks and days from the seconds

```
  //convert to seconds
    sec_in_w = weeks * 604800,
    sec_in_d = days * 86400,
    secs_in_h = hours * 3600,
    secs = sec_in_w + sec_in_d + secs_in_h;
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojLwWo)

Answer (score 0):

Lets see whats happening here:
In the line:

`secs = sec_in_w + sec_in_d + secs_in_h;`

you are adding the value in seconds of 3 weeks + 5 days + 1 hour, or

`secs = 2250000;`

Then you devide by `604800`, and you get `3` as you should, and then you substract this `3` from the big value of secs :). You can do the math yourself:

`(2250000 - 3 ) / 86400 =  26`

exactly what you got :) The same for the hours.

The solution is to first convert your numbers back to their representation in seconds.

```
//convert back to weeks, days, and hours 
new_w = Math.floor(secs / 604800);
secs -= new_w * 604800;
new_d = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
secs -= new_d * 86400;
new_h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
```

By the way, javascript has solutions for handling [dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If you are doing this for the exercise I said nothing of course :)